# Bond slave got IP-address from DHCP in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: netplan

I setup up a bond with 2 devices in ubuntu 18.04.

It looks like the bond0 is comming and i can ping it, but the physical interfaces got an IP-address from my DHCP-Server, too.

IP-address of interface enp3s0 and bond0 are in the same scope, and that ends in trouble.

Any ideas whats wrong with my config?

My netplan-config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
     dhcp4: false
     dhcp6: false
    enp3s0:
     dhcp4: false
     dhcp6: false


  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces:
       - enp2s0
       - enp3s0
      parameters:
        mode: 0
      addresses: [192.168.88.8/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.88.1
      nameservers:
        search: [lan]
        addresses: [127.0.0.1, 192.168.88.1]
```

after appling the config the ip-addresse on the devices look like this:

```
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet **192.168.88.8**  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.88.255
        inet6 fe80::6478:e7ff:fec9:3af4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2001:16b8:42d:e200:81e2:eb92:f8ac:5c22  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:16b8:42d:e200:6478:e7ff:fec9:xxxx prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 66:78:e7:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16003  bytes 2905996 (2.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1280  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12699  bytes 2546657 (2.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 18 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.229.33  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        ether 66:78:e7:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13819  bytes 2678515 (2.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11456  bytes 2425479 (2.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet **192.168.88.193**  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.88.255
        ether 66:78:e7:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2184  bytes 227481 (227.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1243  bytes 121178 (121.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Lokale Schleife)
        RX packets 2793  bytes 302214 (302.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2793  bytes 302214 (302.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
root@gemini:/etc/netplan# netplan --debug generate
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:15612): DEBUG: 19:42:50.224: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:15612): DEBUG: 19:42:50.227: starting new processing pass
** (generate:15612): DEBUG: 19:42:50.227: enp3s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:15612): DEBUG: 19:42:50.227: Configuration is valid
** (generate:15612): DEBUG: 19:42:50.227: enp2s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:15612): DEBUG: 19:42:50.227: Configuration is valid
** (generate:15612): DEBUG: 19:42:50.227: bond0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:15612): DEBUG: 19:42:50.227: Configuration is valid
** (generate:15612): DEBUG: 19:42:50.227: Generating output files..
** (generate:15612): DEBUG: 19:42:50.228: NetworkManager: definition enp2s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:15612): DEBUG: 19:42:50.228: NetworkManager: definition enp3s0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:15612): DEBUG: 19:42:50.228: NetworkManager: definition bond0 is not for us (backend 1)
```

---

```
root@gemini:/mnt/extdisk/B# sudo lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 06
       serial: 66:78:e7:c9:3a:f4
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=169.254.229.33 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII slave=yes speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:b0804000-b0804fff memory:b0800000-b0803fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 11
       serial: 66:78:e7:c9:3a:f4
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII slave=yes speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:b0704000-b0704fff memory:b0700000-b0703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: bond0
       serial: 66:78:e7:c9:3a:f4
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=bonding driverversion=3.7.1 duplex=full firmware=2 ip=192.168.88.8 link=yes master=yes multicast=yes speed=1Gbit/s
```

alternative config

```
root@gemini:/etc/netplan# cat 01-netcfg.yaml
network:
   bonds:
       bond0:
           addresses: [192.168.88.8/24]
           gateway4: 192.168.88.1
           nameservers:
              addresses: [127.0.0.1, 192.168.88.1]
           interfaces:
              - enp2s0
              - enp3s0
   ethernets:
       enp2s0:
         dhcp4:false
       enp3s0:
         dhcp4:false
root@gemini:/etc/netplan# netplan apply
/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml:10:17: Error in network definition: bond0: interface 'enp3s0' is not defined
              - enp3s0
                ^
root@gemini:/etc/netplan#
```